# Android Browser can not support play list with HTML5 Audio in background mode

Tags: android, html, audio, browser, background-process

I want to make Radio Web App Android-browser-based.
The key function for my Web App is continuously playing music-list
(mp3 files) ...
JavaScript Code is simple ...
And it works well in PC Browser, iOS safari, and Android Dolphin
Browser (3rd party browser)...

---

```
var audioPlayer = new Audio();

audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended', nextSong, false);

function nextSong() {
  audioPlayer.src = nextMusic_src; 
}
```

---

But. in Android Default Browser,
when android is in background mode (Home Screen mode & LCD-off Sleep
mode),
Android Browser's onPause()  prevent "ended" event & execution of
nextSong().
So, my web app can play only one music....  and does not work any
more.....
Android Browser's onPause()  source code is like this ...

---

### BrowserActivity.java

```
public class BrowserActivity extends Activity 
{

   private Controller mController;

   // ...

   @Override

   protected void onPause() {

       if (mController != null) {
           mController.onPause();        //   <<==== here
       }
       super.onPause();
   }

}
```

---

### Controller.java

```
public class Controller implements WebViewController, UiController {

   protected void onPause() {

       // ...
       mActivityPaused = true;
       // ...
       mUi.onPause();
       mNetworkHandler.onPause();        //   <<==== here

       WebView.disablePlatformNotifications();      //   <<====here
   }

}
```

---

---

### NetworkStateHandler.java

```
public class NetworkStateHandler {

   // ...

   void onPause() {

       // unregister network state listener

       mActivity.unregisterReceiver(mNetworkStateIntentReceiver);  //  <<==== here

   }

}
```

---

Is there any browser policy for preventing event in background
mode....?
If not, how can I notice this report to the Google developer for
requesting background music play with web app...?
I consider not WebView based web-app (Hybrid) but only browser-based
web-app...
thank you...

Nohyun Kwak

Comment: What version of Droid are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

Droid's ended event doesn't fire consistently. It's fixed in ICS, I hear. But Gingerbread and prior have the issue.

Instead of listening for .ended, can you listen for .timeupdate and in that handler, see if the time is the end of the song? That may solve your issue.